# Moving Camera shake in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a downhill racer and I want to have the camera shake to various degrees to convey that the player is getting faster. Right now I have a GameObject called "CameraHolder" which is a parent to the Main Camera.

I have a script attached to the Holder that follows the player, and another script attached to the camera that is meant to shake it within that holder.

CameraHolder Follow Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public float speed = 2f;
    public Rigidbody rb; 
    public float startingFieldOfView = 60f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float interpolation = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, player.position.x, interpolation), player.position.y + player.localScale.y + offset.y, player.position.z + -player.localScale.z + offset.z);
        
        // Change of camera FOV depending on the speed of the rigidbody
        transform.position = cameraPosition;
       
        cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(cam.fieldOfView, startingFieldOfView + (rb.velocity.magnitude / 3), .1f);
```

CameraShake Script attached to child Main Camera

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraShake : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody player;
    public float shakeThreshold;
    public float shakeMagnitude;

    private void Update()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(-shakeMagnitude, shakeMagnitude);
        float y = Random.Range(-shakeMagnitude, shakeMagnitude);
        if (player.velocity.magnitude >= shakeThreshold)
        {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

I think maybe I misunderstand how localPosition works. I thought that it would move the camera the random amount while moving within the holder, but it does nothing. Am I applying this wrong or is the logic off?

Comment: `localPositon` defines the gameObject position respect to the parent in the hierarchy. Ensure that the `shakeMagnitude` is big enough, that you are entering the `if (player.velocity.magnitude >= shakeThreshold)` (put a breakpoint or a `Debug.Log()` and that the camera component is in the gameobject you are moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using cinemachine will really help you.

To remplace your CameraFollow script you can use a virtual camera with the property Follow, for more information you can go there : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.6/manual/CinemachineSetUpVCam.html

To replace your Camera shake you can check the Noise Property there : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.6/manual/CinemachineVirtualCameraNoise.html

For more information on cinemachine go check the doc here : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.6/manual/CinemachineUsing.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't think I ever would have found this on my own. Exactly what I needed!